# External Javascript is not working on router change in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, dom-events

I'm using external javascript from my assets/js/script.js file in angular to enable buttons that are disabled by default. But it only works on the first page once l route to another component and comes back to the watch page the javascript is not loaded. check below my code.

my .ts file

```
     ngOnInit() {
    // bug fix due js only working on refresh
    this.loadScript('assets/js/script.js');

    this.token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    this.users = this.Token.payload(this.token);
    this.username = this.users.data.name;
    this.email = this.users.data.email;

    this.videoid = this.getVideoId();
    // console.log(this.video);

    // get video by id sent from on click
    this.jarwis.watch({ 'video_id': this.videoid }).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.video = res['video'];
    });
  }

  // load js file in components
  loadScript(url: string) {
    const body = <HTMLDivElement>document.body;
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerHTML = '';
    script.src = url;
    script.async = false;
    script.defer = true;
    body.appendChild(script);
  }
```

my watch.html code

```
      <video controls class="video" id="video" *ngIf="video.video !== '/lessons/'">
    <source src="https://testing.co.za/Backend/{{ video.video }}" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>

      <div class="buttons" *ngIf="video.video !== '/lessons/'">
        <div class="mybuttons">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary next" id="quizBtn" (click)="quiz(video.name)" disabled>
            <span class="ti-agenda"></span>
            QUIZ
          </button>
        </div>

        <div class="divider"></div>

        <div class="mybuttons">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary next" id="bookBtn" (click)="book(video.subtopic)" disabled>
            <span class="ti-calendar"></span>
            Book Tutor
          </button>
        </div>

      </div>
```

my script.js

```
 window.onload = function () {
  el = document.getElementById("video");

  if (el) {
    el.addEventListener("ended", videoEndHandler, false);
  }
};

function videoEndHandler(e) {
  document.getElementById("quizBtn").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("bookBtn").disabled = false;
}
```

How do l make this external js file work even on router change?

Comment: What does Angular have to do with this?

Comment: Hi, @agulowaty l just include it because I'm using angular to feed the HTML  and if it was only HTML it would work because the page will actually refresh but angular doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

l managed to find the answer just in case someone faces the same issue. the answer is below, you only change the HTML and script.

my .html file

```
  <!-- put autoplay back -->
  <video playsinline controls onended="showUpNext()" class="video" id="video" *ngIf="video.video !== '/lessons/'">
    <source src="https://eworksa.co.za/Backend/{{ video.video }}" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>

 <!---Show these buttons if it is a video-->
      <div class="buttons" *ngIf="video.video !== '/lessons/'">
        <div class="mybuttons">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="quizBtn" (click)="quiz(video.name)" disabled>
            <span class="ti-agenda"></span>
            QUIZ
          </button>
        </div>

        <div class="divider"></div>

        <div class="mybuttons">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary next" id="bookBtn" (click)="book(video.subtopic)" disabled>
            <span class="ti-calendar"></span>
            Book Tutor
          </button>
        </div>

      </div>
```

my script.js

```
   function showUpNext() {
  $("button").removeAttr("disabled");
}
```